# Visual studio profiler shows no code was running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

Visual studio profiler shows that "No code was running during the selected time range", even when there was clearly code running (the time range was the entire execution time of the program). I have tried to reinstall C++ profiling tools but this issue is still here.

Comment: have you ever found a solution? Getting the same thing in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2.1

Comment: I just reinstalled Visual Studio (The repair option in VS Installer).

Comment: People have reported this being fixed by 1) Repairing your VS 2019 installation or 2) Disabling RealTek/NVIDIA high definition audio drivers